# How to import Text Delimited File to SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

In general I know how to import tab delimited file or comma delimited file. One of my client sent me delimited file. Example you can see below. And I don't how to import it without quotes.

```
"Make","Model","ModelYear","Trim","BodyStyle","Mileage","EngineDescription","Cylinders","FuelType","Transmission"
"Dodge","Stealth","1993","ES","Hatchback","107000","V-6","6-Cylinder","Gasoline",""
"GMC","Envoy XL","2003","SLE","Sport Utility","116000","6cyl","6-Cylinder","Gasoline","Automatic"
```

Could you guide me how to import and what settings do I need to change in order to import it with import wizard?

Thank you

Comment: The big problems will start when the '"' character is embedded in the text field and not part of the field qualifier. That can't easily be handled on import.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the "Text qualifier" to `"`.

[image]

Comment: An answer like this has just saved me hours and hours of work. Thanks.

Comment: Where does this wizard reside?

Answer (score 6):

People might say it's a bit krufty, but the easiest way might be to open it as a CSV in excel and then copy/paste it right into your table using Management Studio.

If you are trying to do anything fancier than that, this method won't work.  If not, you would be hard pressed to find a faster way to do it.

Comment: I didn't know you could paste multiple rows like that. That is pretty fantastically useful, thanks!

Comment: in my case, the file was coming with text in different languages. all characters not found in the common character set of english was being reformated  eg.  é > Ã©. made a huge mess of my file after it opened

Answer (score 1):

If the data is very simplistic you can use the SSMS import wizard.  Right click the database, select tasks, select Import Data, and has been pointed out identify quotes as the text qualifier.

For a csv, tab delimited file you would change Data Source option to:  Flat File Source

From there just answer the questions and follow the prompts.

I will warn you however.  Unless the data is very simplistic, this method tends to produce a lot of errors.  I almost always end up using [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx) which is a little more hassle and complex but a whole lot more powerful and dependable.

Comment: +1 not least for for the "lots of errors" comment.  Still quite easy to get lots of errors with SSIS, but at least you can usually do something about them when you've a package at hand!

Comment: I just love that 'have a guess at my column types' button.  Never fails to get it wrong.  :)